# Determining which of the following statements is true about Linear mapping and isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Which of the following statements is true?
>
> 1. Given the linear map $T: \Bbb R^4 \to \Bbb R^3$ such that $KerT=Sp\{(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)\}$ and $T(1,0,0,0)=T(0,1,0,0)$
> 2. there is isomorphism between the subspaces $U=Sp\{(5,2,4,3),(1,2,2,1),(3,-2,0,1)\}$ of $\Bbb R^4$ to the subspace $W=\{p(x) \in \Bbb R_3[x]| p(0)=p(1)\}$ $(\Bbb R_3[x]=\{ax^2+bx+c|a,b,c \in \Bbb R\}$ **(This is the correct answer)**
> 3. there exists a linear map $T:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ such that $T(1,1,0)=(1,-2,0)$ , $T(1,-1,0)=(1,0,1)$ , $T(1,10,0)=(0,0,1)$

---

According to the textbook the correct answer is $2$ , but I wanted to solve all of them to understand the topic so the final result is not really important.

My try:

**For the first statement** I used counter example - first I checked linear independence according to the vectors of the kernel and go the $\alpha(0,0,1,0)+\beta(0,0,0,1)=0$ is linearly independent therefore $dim(kerT)=2$ then I tried building a linear mapping that fulfills what the question says. I used the standard basis for $\Bbb R^4$ $(e_1=(1,0,0,0)\qquad \qquad e_2=(0,1,0,0) \qquad \qquad e_3=(0,0,1,0) \qquad e_4=(0,0,0,1)$ on the set $W=(0,0,(1,0,0),(1,0,0))$ such that we get
$T(e_1)=(1,0,0)$ $\qquad$  $T(e_2)=(1,0,0)$ $\qquad$  $T(e_3)=0$ $\qquad$  $T(e_4)=0$

from here we have $T(e_1)=T(e_2)$ as the question asks and also $KerT=Sp\{e_3,e_4\}$

but we get that $dim(ImT)=1$ and $dim(KerT)=2$ so $dim(V) \not= dim(KerT)+dim(ImT)$

**For the second statement (which is the correct statement) -** we need to prove that the dimensions are equal then it will be isomorphic. so I checked linear independence and got $\alpha(5,2,4,3)+ \beta(1,2,2,1) + \gamma (3,-2,0,1)=0$ so after elementary operations on the matrix we get $ \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
  1&2&2&1\\
  0&4&3&1\\
  0&0&0&0\\
\end{array}
\right)$
so since it has the zero vector it is linearly dependent therefore we can eliminate one vector of the span and we get $U=Sp\{(1,2,2,1),(0,4,3,1)\}$ and $dim(U)=2$ but I failed to find $dim(W)$

**For the third statement -** let $v_1 = (1,1,0)$ , $v_2 = (1,-1,0)$ and $v_3 =(1,0,0)$
I put them in a matrix as columns and got $ \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  1&0&1\\
  0&1&0\\
  0&0&0\\
\end{array}
\right)$ so they are linearly dependent ( I do not know if this is actually needed) but I tried checking $T(v_1+v_2)=T(v_1)+T(v_2)$ and got $T(v_1+v_2)=T(\left(
\begin{array}{c}
  2\\
  0\\
  0\\
\end{array}
\right))$ and $T(v_1)+T(v_2)=$
$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
  1\\
  -2\\
  0\\
\end{array}
\right)$
$+$
$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
  1\\
  0\\
  1\\
\end{array}
\right)$
$=$
$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
  2\\
  -2\\
  1\\
\end{array}
\right)$

So I think it is not correct because $T(\left(
\begin{array}{c}
  2\\
  0\\
  0\\
\end{array}
\right))$ is not defined?

My questions:

1. is my way correct for the first statement?
2. how do I find the $dim(W)$ in the second statement
3. how do I approach the third statement?

thanks for any tips and help , and sorry if the translations are wrong hope it is understandable!

Comment: (1) What is the statement? 
(2) What does $p(0)=p(1)$ say about the coefficients a,b,c?

Comment: (3) What is the dimension of the subspace $U$ spanned by $\{(1,1,0), (1,-1,0), (1,10,0)\}$ and what is the dimension of the of the image of T restricted to $U$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not understand the first statement. For the context in your answer below I suppose that in the first part is "there exists a linear map...".

**Answer for the first question:**

- Since ${\rm ker}(T)={\rm span}\{(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1) \}$ and the set $S:=\{(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)\}$ is linearly independent on $\mathbb{R}^{4}$. Hence a basis for ${\rm ker}$ of the linear map $T: \mathbb{R}^{4}\to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ is given by $\beta=\{(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)\}$, (spanning "+" independence give a basis). Therefore, $\dim {\rm ker}(T)=2$.
- If the question is: "Is there exists a linear map $T: \mathbb{R}^{4}\to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that ${\rm ker}(T)={\rm span}\{(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)\}$ and $T(1,0,0,0)=T(0,1,0,0)$?" so the answer is no. Indeed, suppose that there exists such a linear map,  we should have a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ of the form $\beta'=\{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)\}=\{e_{1},e_{2},e_{3},e_{4}\}$ such that $T(e_{1})=(1,0,0), T(e_{2})=(1,0,0), T(e_{3})=(0,0,0)$ and $T(e_{4})=(0,0,0)$. Hence the image ${\rm im}$ for $T$ is given by
  \begin{align*}
  {\rm im}(T)&=\{(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{R}^{3}: \exists (x,y,z,w)\in \mathbb{R}^{4}: T(x,y,z,w)=(a,b,c)\}\\
  &=\left\{(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{R}^{3}: \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x\\ y \\ z \\ w\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix} \right \}\\
  &=\left\{(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{R}^{3}: a\in \mathbb{R}, b=c=0\right\}\\
  &={\rm span}\{(1,0,0)\}
  \end{align*}
  So $\dim {\rm im}(T)=1$. But it is a contradiction for the the fact well-known $\dim {\rm im}(T)+\dim {\rm ker}(T)=\dim V$, because we have $1+2\not=4$.
- Therefore there is not exists such linear map.

**Answer for the second question:**

- We know that the subspaces $W,U$ of vector space $V$ with $V$ finite-dimensional are isomorphic iff $\dim(V)=\dim(U)$ and it is denote by $W\cong U$.
- Since $U={\rm span}\{(5,2,4,3),(1,2,2,1),(3,-2,0,1)\}$ and since $$\begin{bmatrix} 5 & 2 & 4 & 3\\ 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\ 3 & -2 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\sim \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 2 & 4 & 3\\ 0 & \frac{8}{3} & \frac{6}{5} & \frac{2}{5} \\ 3 & -2 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\sim \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 2 & 4 & 3 \\ 0 & \frac{8}{3} & \frac{6}{5} & \frac{2}{5} \\ 0 & -\frac{16}{5} & -\frac{12}{5} & -\frac{4}{5}\end{bmatrix}\sim \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 2 & 4 & 3\\ 0 & 8 & 6 & 2\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
  Hence the set $S=\{((5,2,4,3),(1,2,2,1),(3,-2,0,1)\}$ is linearly dependent and we can delete a vector of $S$, then we have $U={\rm span}\{(5,2,4,3),(1,2,2,1)\}$. Hence $\dim U=2$.
- Notice that,
  \begin{align*}
  W&=\{p(x)\in \mathbb{R}_{2}[x]:p(0)=p(1) \}\\
  &=\{ax^{2}+bx+c\in \mathbb{R}_{2}[x]: a(0)^{2}+b(0)+c=a(1)^{2}+b(1)+c\}\\
  &=\{ax^{2}+bx+c\in \mathbb{R}_{2}[x]:c=a+b+c\}\\
  &=\{ax^{2}+bx+c\in \mathbb{R}_{2}[x]:a+b=0, c\in \mathbb{R}\}\\
  &=\{ax^{2}+bx+c\in \mathbb{R}_{2}[x]:a=-b, c,b\in \mathbb{R}\}\\
  &={\rm span}\{-x^{2}+x,1\}
  \end{align*}
  Hence $\dim W=2$.
- Therefore $W\cong U$.

**Answer for thr third question:**

- Suppose that there exists such linear map.
- Notice that $S=\{(1,1,0),(1,-1,0),(1,10,0)\}$ is linearly dependent because $\det\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 10 & 0\end{bmatrix}=0$ so we know there exists scalar $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha(1,1,0)+\beta(1,-1,0)=(1,10,0)$. Then solving the linear system we get $\alpha=11/2$ and $\beta=-9/2$.  Hence $$\frac{11}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} -\frac{9}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 10\\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
- Since $T$ is a linear map, by definition we must have
  $$\frac{11}{2}T\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} -\frac{9}{2}T\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}=T\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 10\\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
  but it does not hold, because
  $$\frac{11}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}-\frac{9}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\not=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$
- Therefore such linear map there is not exists.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is a linear map $T:\mathbb{R}^{4} \to \mathbb{R^3}$ such that ker $T = \text{span}\{e_3,e_4\}$ and $Te_1=Te_2$. By the Rank-Null theorem, this is impossible.
2. There is an isomorphism between $U \subset \mathbb{R^4}$ and $W \subset \mathbb{R}_3[x]$. We have $U \simeq \mathbb{R^2} \simeq W$ noting that $W=\{p(x) \in \mathbb{R}_3[x]: p(0)=p(1) \}=\{p(x) \in \mathbb{R}_3[x]: p(x)=a(x^2-x)+b\}$.
3. Let $U=\text{span}\{(1,1,0),(1,-1,0),(1,10,0)\}$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$. We have $\text{dim} \ U=2$ and the map $S=T|_{U}:U \to \mathbb{R^3}$ is linear and $\text{dim Im} \ S = 3$. Conclude accordingly.